# Annual price of precious metals

Tags: data-request, commodities

I need a list (or separate lists) with average prices of precious metals (gold, silver, platinum, palladium, etc.), by year. I prefer the annual average price or at least the price at the end/beginning of the year and I do not need graphs with prices fluctuations from one day/week/month to another.

Also price ratios (like gold/silver, gold/platinum - e.g. "in year 1900, with 33.33 ounces of silver you could buy one ounce of gold") are very useful for me.

International prices are desired of course, but the national prices are also very welcomed (like historical price of gold in the UK/US/France/Germany or any other country where someone actually bothered to record such facts).

Comment: What time interval?

Comment: Maximum time interval possible. A list with prices in the last 20 years is very good. A list with 50 years is even better. And so on. I am not waiting for a single best answer. Any such answer is very good for me. There might be a "best answer for gold", "best answer for silver", etc. though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options for data. With questions of this nature, Quandl is your friend.

- [See here](https://www.quandl.com/data/NMA/HIST_GOLD_PR-Historical-Gold-Prices-1833-Present) for historical gold prices, 1833 until present. I've not read about the methodology here though.
- [This resource](https://www.quandl.com/data/MWORTH/10_3-Gold-Silver-Price-Ratio) has the gold/silver price ratio. Annual data. It seems pretty easy to transform this into price of silver.
- [For platinum](https://www.quandl.com/data/JOHNMATT/PLAT-Platinum-Prices)
- It also looks like the [Perth Mint](https://www.quandl.com/data/PERTH?keyword=historical%20platinum%20price) keeps a decent amount of historical data. I noticed in that list paladium as well.
- The [Reserve Bank of Scotland](http://www.databank.rbs.com/default.aspx) has a set which can give you prices of commodities, monthly and daily going back 15 years. I am not sure if there are any precious metals in that list.